# gitlab - get artifacts from triggered pipeline in other repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm to trying to trigger a pipeline in a separate project and then collect the artifacts, but I'm keep getting CI lint errors when adding the `needs` section. The trigger itself is working.

This is the stage:

```
trigger_integration_test:
    stage: test_on_dev
    variables:
        TEST_TYPE: ci
    trigger:
        project: <FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT>
        strategy: depend
    needs:    
    - project: <FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT>
    job: integration_tests_on_test
    ref: main
    artifacts: true
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding a separate stage, to run after the tests to collect the artifacts:

```
download_gauge_tests_artifacts:
  stage: test_on_dev
  script:
    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --request GET "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectid>/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=integration_tests_on_test"'
    - unzip artifacts.zip
    - rm -rf artifacts.zip
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - reports/*
    when: always
```